# Spark Categorical Data Encoding

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

Is there a function in Spark to do Categorical data encoding.
Ex:

```
Var1,Var2,Var3
1,2,a
2,3,b
3,2,c
```

To

```
var1,var2,var3
1,2,0
2,3,1
3,2,2

a -> 0, b->1, c->2
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this function for Categorical data encoding.

## python

```
def get_mapping(rdd, idx):
    return rdd.map(lambda x: x[idx]).distinct().zipWithIndex().collectAsMap()
```

## Scala

```
val categories = rdd.map(r => r(2)).distinct.collect.zipWithIndex.toMap
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python - PySpark 2.0.0 +

```
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv",keep_default_na=False)
df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
types =  df1.dtypes
arity = {}
i=0
for c,t in types:
    if(t == 'string'):
        arity[i] = len(df1.select(c).distinct().collect())
        print arity[i],i,c
    i+=1
```

This arity dictionary can act as your input to *categoricalFeaturesInfo*